# How can I refactor the mass if-else statement?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, refactoring

How can I refactor the mass if-else statement??  I have lots of big if-else statements in my app, do I need to refactor all this code or just leave it alone?

```
if (up > 80 && up < 140)
{
    if (distance)
    {
        go.transform.position = go2.transform.position;
    }
    go.transform.Translate(y, 0, x);
}
else
{
    if (down > 140)
    {
        if (distance)
        {
            go.transform.position = go2.transform.position;
        }
        go.transform.Translate(0, -y, x);
    }
    else if (down < 35)
    {
        if (distance)
        {
            go.transform.position = go2.transform.position;
        }
        go.transform.Translate(0, -y, -x);
    }
    else if (down > 35 && down < 140 && right > 0)
    {
        if (distance)
        {
            go.transform.position = go2.transform.position;
        }
        go.transform.Translate(-x, -y, 0);
    }
    else if (down > 35 && down < 140 && right < 0)
    {
        if (distance)
        {
            go.transform.position = go2.transform.position;
        }
        go.transform.Translate(x, -y, 0);
    }
}
```

How can I refactor the mass if-else statement??  I have lots of big if-else statements in my app, do I need to refactor all this code or just leave it alone?

Comment: Start simple, and fix one thing at a time. Start by making those magic numbers named variables, 35 and 140 mean nothing to me now and will mean nothing to you if you don’t read it for a month 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
private static void Foo(bool distance, YourGoClass go, YourGoClass go2, double x, double y, double z)
{
    if (distance) go.transform.position = go2.transform.position;
    go.transform.Translate(x, y, z);
}
```

And then you can change your code like this

```
if (up > 80 && up < 140)
{
    Foo(distance, go, go2, y, 0, x);
}
else
{
    switch(down)
    {
        case var _ when down > 140:
            Foo(distance, go, go2, 0, -y, x);
            break;
        case var _ when down < 35:
            Foo(distance, go, go2, 0, -y, -x);
            break;
        default:
            if (right > 0) Foo(distance, go, go2, -x, -y, 0);
            else Foo(distance, go, go2, x, -y, 0);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method like this:

```
private static void Translate(bool distance, YourGoClas go, YourGoClas go2, double x, double y, double z)
{
    if (distance)
    {
        go.transform.position = go2.transform.position;
    }

    go.transform.Translate(x, y, z);
}
```

And refactor:

```
if (up > 80 && up < 140)
{
    Translate(distance, go, go2, y, 0, x);
}
else
{
    if (down < 35)
    {
        Translate(distance, go, go2, 0, -y, -x);
    }
    else if (down < 140)
    {
        if (right > 0)
        {
            Translate(distance, go, go2, -x, -y, 0);
        }
        else if (right < 0)
        {
            Translate(distance, go, go2, x, -y, 0);
        }
    }
    else // if (down > 140)
    {
        Translate(distance, go, go2, 0, -y, x);
    }
}
```

The key is look for code almost equal and run in a separate method. And try to do if conditions in order, only a single comparison when it's allow you separate all cases.

Comment: If you make that snippet a void Method, you don't even need all of the `else`s. Just return early.

Comment: @Fildor Thanks for the note, but in this case it is deliberately so. When code blocks refer to different cases of the same data, I like to have them all at the same depth level (as in a swicth). I prefer if/else in this case before do return and put at distinct deep, data of same type. In other cases I use return to avoid increment the cyclomatic complexity. For me (it's something personal), maybe have sense only in the up and down case.

Comment: Well, to me, this is still somewhat unreadable (at least a pain). It's spaghetti code, it uses magic numbers ... but I really like your version of applying DRY over the other answers.

Comment: @Fildor I know that return version is less complex but if I check 3 values of down, I read better if they are in the same block level. The return move the next block to the left (less cyclomatic complexity) and I see more unreadable (just the opposite to you).

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. I am still thinking about something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could apply `extract method` which reduces duplicated code.

```
private void setPositionByDistance(boolean distance, Go go, Go go2) {
    if (distance)
    {
        go.transform.position = go2.transform.position;
    }
}
```

And use `early return` pattern, which reduces unnecessary nested `if-else` hierarchy.

Then your code will become better:

```
if (up > 80 && up < 140)
{
    setPositionByDistance(distance, go, go2);
    go.transform.Translate(y, 0, x);
    return;  // early return
}

if (down > 140)
{
    setPositionByDistance(distance, go, go2);
    go.transform.Translate(0, -y, x);
}
else if (down < 35)
{
    setPositionByDistance(distance, go, go2);
    go.transform.Translate(0, -y, -x);
}
else if (down > 35 && down < 140 && right > 0)
{
    setPositionByDistance(distance, go, go2);
    go.transform.Translate(-x, -y, 0);
}
else if (down > 35 && down < 140 && right < 0)
{
    setPositionByDistance(distance, go, go2);
    go.transform.Translate(x, -y, 0);
}
```